# Specifying cc address with sendmail in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, email, sendmail

A typical use / call of the MATLAB `sendmail` function looks like this:

```
% content
body = 'text';
attachments = 'attachment.pdf';

% set preferences
setpref('Internet', 'SMTP_Server', 'smtp.office365.com');
setpref('Internet', 'E_mail', 'first.last@domain.com');
setpref('Internet', 'SMTP_Username', 'first.last@domain.com');
setpref('Internet', 'SMTP_Password', '123456');

% properties
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth', 'true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.port', '587');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.starttls.enable', 'true' );

% send message
sendmail(address, subject, body, attachment);
```

Additional functionality that I am not able to get clarity on is how to specify cc address(es)?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB `sendmail` is not a full-fledged email client. It is meant to send an email for example informing you that computations have finished. Consequently, it doesn’t support CC or BCC, nor HTML emails, only plain-text emails.

If you are trying to use `sendmail` to send emails to clients, for example, you are using the wrong tool.

If you are on Windows, you could [use ActiveX/COM to communicate with the MS Outlook app](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94446-can-i-send-e-mail-through-matlab-using-microsoft-outlook), and use that to construct abs send emails. But likely there are better tools than MATLAB to programmatically send mass emails.

Comment: Shameless plug: I'm working on a Matlab library "MailSpoon" to address exactly this use case: https://github.com/janklab/MailSpoon. Full-featured SMTP email and generation of rich HTML email messages.